# hibernate interceptor onsave method with null Serializable id

Tags: hibernate

I have extended the EmptyInterceptor and I want to log a newly created entity id. In the onSave method Serializable id is null and the entity primary key is also null. we are using hbm file to mapped the pojo class and generator class="identity" for primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the [EmptyInterceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#onSave%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]%29) will be called before the entity is saved.

Try using [postFlush](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#postFlush%28java.util.Iterator%29), where the ID will be available.

Here is a small example with `Hibernate 4.3`:

`Entity Student.java`

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

`Interceptor class: LogInterceptor.java`

```
public class LogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        System.out.println("Entered onSave : class - " + entity.getClass());
        if (entity instanceof Student) {
            Student s = (Student) entity;
            System.out.println("class:" + entity.getClass() + " , id: "+s.getId());
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("Entered postFlush");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = iterator.next();
            if (obj instanceof Student) {
                Student s = (Student) obj;
                System.out.println("class:" + s.getClass() + " , id: "+s.getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }
}
```

`Code to test this:`

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setInterceptor( new LogInterceptor() );
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setName("Test");
        session.save(s1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

`Output:`

```
Entered onSave : class - class Student
class:class Student , id: 1

Entered postFlush
class:class Student , id: 1
```

In my example I got the ID at `onSave` method itself.

Comment: so how do i get the entity primary key in onSave method